# Result type cast error when doing calculations with Pytorch model parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, runtime-error

When I ran the code below:

```
import torchvision

model = torchvision.models.densenet201(num_classes=10)
params = model.state_dict()
for var in params:
    params[var] *= 0.1
```

a RuntimeError was reported:

```
RuntimeError: result type Float can't be cast to the desired output type Long
```

But when I changed `params[var] *= 0.1` to `params[var] = params[var] * 0.1`, the error disappears.

Why would this happen?

I thought `params[var] *= 0.1` had the same effect as `params[var] = params[var] * 0.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let us know the first long-type parameter in `densenet201`, you will find the `features.norm0.num_batches_tracked` which indicates the number of mini-batches during training used to calculate the mean and variance if there is BatchNormalization layer in the model. `This parameter is a long-type number and cannot be float type because it behaves like a counter`.

Second, in PyTorch, there are two types of operations:

- **Non-Inplace operations:** you assign the new output after calculation to a new copy from the variable, e.g. x = x + 1 or x = x / 2. The memory location of x before assignment not equal to the memory location after assignment because you have a copy from the original variable.
- **Inplace operations:** when the calculations directly applied to the original copy of the variable without making any copy here e.g. x += 1 or x /= 2.

Let's move to your example to understand what happened:

1. Non-Inplcae operation:

   ```
   model = torchvision.models.densenet201(num_classes=10)
   params = model.state_dict()
   name = 'features.norm0.num_batches_tracked'

   print(id(params[name]))  # 140247785908560
   params[name] = params[name] + 0.1
   print(id(params[name]))  # 140247785908368  
   print(params[name].type()) # changed to torch.FloatTensor
   ```
2. Inplace operation:

   ```
   print(id(params[name]))  # 140247785908560
   params[name] += 1
   print(id(params[name]))  # 140247785908560 
   print(params[name].type()) # still torch.LongTensor

   params[name] += 0.1     # you want to change the original copy type to float ,you got an error
   ```

Finally, some remarks:

- In-place operations save some memory, but can be problematic when computing derivatives because of an immediate loss of history. Hence, their use is discouraged. [Source](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html#operations)
- You should be cautious when you decide to use in-place operations since they overwrite the original content.
- If you use pandas, this is a bit similar to the `inplace=True` in pandas :).

This is a good resource to read more about in-place operation [source](https://towardsdatascience.com/in-place-operations-in-pytorch-f91d493e970e) and read also this discussion [source](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-in-place-operation/16244/15).

Comment: Thank you so much for this very detailed answer! It really helps me understand how python works.